# THE MEMOIR CLASS - using \addcontentsline{toc}{part} within Memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I've introduced some parts in my file that are coded like this : `\part*{title of the part}`. So, in order to have them added to the Table of content, I use : `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}`.

But I'm facing something strange with the following lines :

[image]

If I'm correct I've not changed many thing between the code for "Conclusion" and the one for "Annexes et Tables". So I don't see the problem...

But If I do this :

[image]

So, both entries appear in the ToC but "Annexes et Tables" appears before I actually introduce the `\part*{Annexes et Tables}` line of code...so That's not what I want and both have the same page number which is not a problem while I've not written any of those two parts but when i'll have finished down the line, I'll be stuck...

And if I push my luck as far as deleting `\part*{Annexes et tables}`, just to see what happens :

[image]

Both lines disappear in the PDF file...

Just to give a further piece of information : i've got at the beginning of my document a non-numbered part called "Introduction" and that one suffer from no problem at all. So I don't know what's causing this problem here....

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Elrad

Comment: Will there be any numbered or unnumbered sectioning commands following `\part*{Annexes et Tables}`?

Comment: Yes there will be some` \chapter*{...}` under the `\part*{Annexes et Tables}` part

Comment: As soon as I add a `\chapter*` or any other sectioning command after the `\part*{Annexes...}` the table of contents will displayed correctly, provided that I use your first approach.

Comment: Here is a MWE: `\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Conclusion}

\part*{Annexe}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Annexe}
\chapter*{some chapter}

\end{document}`

Comment: @leandriis your idea is the good one, if I simply introduce another element after that unnumbered part, it works. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `\addcontentsline...` to put a title into the ToC then that code should be placed after you have coded for the title in the document.

```
% lots of stuff
% \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Title} % not this
\part*{Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Title}   % but this
```

Comment: that's what I did in my first example albeit separated by green dots like this`%----%`